# About Java EE classpath

Tags: classpath, jakarta-mail

I am developing an online conference system based on Java EE framework using NetBeans for my school.  My project contains the Java EE library which has `javax.mail` package.

I use the `javax.mail.authenticator` class in my code and everything seems to be OK. However, when I run the project and try to send email with this system, problem occurs, saying it can not find class `javax.mail.authenticator`.

Then I put the files mail.jar and authenticator.jar in folder WEB-INF/lib, after that it can send email correctly. I don't know why it can not find the class authenticator and why this two jar files should be put there?

PS: I use Tomcat 6 as my web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between having a class on the Java build path, and on the classpath. By putting `mail.jar` and `authenticator.jar` into `WEB-INF/lib`, you have put them into Tomcat's classpath so that Tomcat can "see" those classes at runtime.

#### Recommended reading: [What is the difference between Class Path and Build Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529459/what-is-the-difference-between-class-path-and-build-path)

P.S. I think you mean Java EE. It hasn't been called J2EE for ~5 years now.

Comment: Thank you very much.Then what should I do if I want to use javax.mail package and classes in it?

Comment: @Jude you did the correct thing, dropping the JARs into `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have got the right answer.Maybe I should install java EE SDK instead of java SE JDK.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy an application to a Java EE container, like Tomcat, there are certain places classes and jars are loaded to form an application's classpath.  For web applications (a war), classes are loaded from WEB-INF/classes and from jars in the WEB-INF/lib.