# What's is the difference between building path and source package?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Class Path and Build Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529459/what-is-the-difference-between-class-path-and-build-path)

I am using eclipse to build a dynamic web project with struts2 framework. At first, I put the struts.xml under the WEB-INF directory and build path to it, but I failed to run the web project. After I make a source package under the src diretory and put struts.xml in it, the web project can run normally.

I am confused about that put a java file in source package means put the responding compiled class in the bin directory and class_path which makes the other classes can find it, then what does build path action in eclipse do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A source path entry is a folder, where  Eclipse will look for JAVA files, a build path entry is a place (folder/jar), where Eclipse/java will look for CLASS files.

All the files from a source path entry will get compiled (if .java) and then copied (alongside other, non java files) to the output folder specified in project configuration. Those files are relevant to **javaC**, the compiler.

Build Path entries are only relevant to **java**, the runtime.