# Maven compiler:compile goal plugin lack of specification?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

In the Maven super-pom.xml definition (4.0.0)
in the build section are defined some configuration parameters,
such as:

```
<build> 
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory> <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
...
<build>
```

Now let's take for example :`<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>`

**resources:resources** plugin goal uses it,
as described in the documentation:

> Name  Type    Since   Description outputDirectory File    -   The output
>   directory into which to copy the resources. Default value is:
>   ${project.build.outputDirectory}.

**compiler:compile** plugin goal uses it as well (I guess),
but it is nowhere   defined in the documentation of that plugin.
Why is that ? is it a lack in the specification or what ?
am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't get it, Could you post an answer elaborating your point please, it would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: I mean you could answer elaborating your previous comment, for example what does "There can be generated sources at build-time" mean ? surely I'm missing something...

Comment: Also "maven-compiler-plugin will compile all Java sources in the buildpath.", what do you mean by the buildpath ?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the `maven-compiler-plugin` is to compile all Java files present under source directories, i.e. [on the buildpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3529514/1743880). It is true that, by default, `src/main/java` is a source directory. However, there can be many other sources directories.

- You can add a source directory on-the-fly during the Maven build itself with the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) goal.
- A Maven plugin can generate itself Java source code. The [FAQ](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/faq.html) of the compiler plugin even mentions that case . And there are a lot of plugins that generate Java source code, based on a XSD, a WSDL, a database schema, a custom model... Maven itself uses [Modello](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-modello.html), which is a tool generating Java code from a model.

All those options revolve around the same idea: adding Java sources into the buildpath. And all those sources will need to be compiled by the compiler plugin.

So really, the only concern of the `maven-compiler-plugin` is: compile what is under the buildpath. My guess is that this is why the documentation of the plugin is the way it is. The [`compile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) goal has for unique documentation:

> Compiles application sources

And it kind of makes sense: there isn't much to specify since those sources can have a variety of origins, so the documentation stays generic. It only specifies what it needs to: compile what is under the buildpath.

---

I'll add that this isn't specific to the compiler plugin. As you said in your question, this also concerns the `maven-resources-plugin`. Everything that has been said before in this answer also applies in the case of the resources plugin:

- You can add a resource directory during the build with the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-resource`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-resource-mojo.html) goal.
- A Maven plugin could also generate resources during the build (for example a WSDL generated by Java annotated classes).

And you'll note that the documentation of the [`resources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) goal is:

> Copy resources for the main source code to the main output directory.

It doesn't specify that `src/main/resources` is a default resource directory, surely for the same reason as the compiler plugin didn't.

However, as you said in your question, [it does document](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#outputDirectory) clearly where those resources are placed. But this is because whatever the origin of those resources (`src/main/resources`, generated...), all of them will always be placed under this output directory.